# dynamically submit form based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to submit form(or setting value for action) with following details

1. if 'cash' is selected then go to a.php
2. else go to b.php
   clicking on submit button.

```html
<tr>  
    <td>
        <label for="payment">Payment Mode:</label>
    </td>  
    <td>
        <select id="payment" name="payment" required="required">  
            <option value="">Select one...</option>  
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>  `enter code here`
            <option value="Draft">Draft</option>                                                                   
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote (and at least what you've tried so far) for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: You basically just explained the exact logic in english. What part of coding it is giving you issues? psuedocode: `if ( getValueOfSelectWithIdPayment === 'Cash') submitTo a.php else submitTo b.php`

Comment: how to get solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice would be to always go to the same php file on submit, and there check `if($_POST["payment"] == "cash")`.

Comment: want two different action to perform which is based on selection of payment mode

Comment: that is exactly what you achieve with that :) `if($_POST["payment"] == "cash") { /*doyourfirstaction*/ } else { /*doyoursecondaction*/ }`

Comment: how to call this /*doyourfirstaction*/ and /*doyoursecondaction*/. how action value will set.

Comment: You don't set action value. You always go so the same php file. For example myActions.php. In that file you use the code mentioned above.

Comment: by doing this data are not populated if use this method while if put value into action form then its populating

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: there is  more input field in form. if we set action="a.php" then all the value   get submitted into database but if try to do this method, we reaches the page but unable to submit data into database..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet doing what you want:

```
$("#payment").on("change", function() {
    if($(":selected", this).val() === "Cash") {
        $("#YourFormId").attr("action", "a.php");
    };
    else {
        $("#YourFormId").attr("action", "b.php");
    }
    $("#YourFormId").submit();
});
```

That will attach a `change` event handler to your `select`, check the value of the selected option and setting the correct action of your form according to your conditions

But you need to change the form selector for targetting the form you want to submit.

And a working [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u40sjws9/)